# Sorting on two columns in vim

Tags: sorting, vim

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
FirstName SurName;Length;Weight;
```

I need to sort on length, and if the length is equal for one or more names, I need to sort those on weight. `sort ni` sorts only on length, I tried `sort /.\{-}\ze\dd/` that too, but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using an external (GNU) sort pretty straightforwardly:

```
!sort -t ';' -k 2,2n -k 3,3n
```

This says: split fields by semicolon, sort by 2nd field numerically, then by 3rd field numerically. Probably a lot easier to read and remember than whatever vim-internal command you can cook up.

Much more info on GNU sort here: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `r` flag.

Sort on Length:

```
:%sort rni /.*;\ze\d/
```

Sort on Weight:

```
:%sort rni /\d+\ze;$/
```

Without this flag, the sorting is performed on what comes *after* the match, which can be a little cumbersome.

With the `r` flag, the sorting is done on the match itself which may be easier to define. Here, the pattern matches a series of 1 or more digits just before a semicolon at the end of the line.

Comment: `:sort` has the same effect of `:%sort` with one less keystroke :) - and the question is how to sort on length, and your regex matches the weight.

Comment: You are right about `:%sort` vs `:sort`, of course. But I propose two commands: one for weight and the other for length.